# Need details about APIs for customization of Tridion Content Delivery

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

Am just 6 months old to Tridion.
I know the basic stuff related to this tool.
I read somewhere saying we can enhance the functionalities of Content Delivery by extending it using some Java APIs.

Could someone guide me where can we get these Java API's from.
It would be great if you can quote some examples for this.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what you're trying to do? This is extremely vague "I read somewhere saying we can enhance the functionalities of Content Delivery by extending it using some Java APIs." and against Stack Overflow's programming-oriented Q&A philosophy

Comment: You can download the API documentation from SDLTridionWorld docs: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/documentation/SDLTridion2011SP1/index.aspx (you need a login).  Also, please consider committing to the Area 51 proposal at area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/… so that we can get a dedicated SDL Tridion Q&A area.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apart from the official documentation (http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_35CC2F9DCEA34995931E181C165FCC0F, login required) there is an excellent series of articles on the topic by Mihai Cadariu: http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/extending-content-delivery-storage-sdltridion-2011-1.aspx.

I suggest you start from there and let us know if you have more specific questions!

Comment: Thanks a lot Quirijn for guidelines.